# Entity framework core doesn't create migration file

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have done my model structure and ran

> sudo dotnet ef migrations add 3-MyMigration

command but there is no file created in the Migration folder.

Here is the output :

```
 Project SocioFal (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0) will be compiled because project is not safe for incremental compilation. Use --build-profile flag for more information.
 Compiling SocioFal for .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0
 Bundling with configuration from /home/aymeric/dotnet_projects/sociofal/SocioFal/bundleconfig.json
 Processing wwwroot/css/site.min.css
 Processing wwwroot/js/site.min.js
 Compilation succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)
 Time elapsed 00:00:04.0311963
 (The compilation time can be improved. Run "dotnet build --build-profile" for more information)
```

And with verbose tag :

```
Project SocioFal (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0) will be compiled because project is not safe for incremental compilation. Use --build-profile flag for more information.
Compiling SocioFal for .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0
Bundling with configuration from /home/aymeric/dotnet_projects/sociofal/SocioFal/bundleconfig.json
Processing wwwroot/css/site.min.css
Processing wwwroot/js/site.min.js
Compilation succeeded.
0 Warning(s)
0 Error(s)
Time elapsed 00:00:13.1481501
(The compilation time can be improved. Run "dotnet build --build-profile" for more information)
Setting app base path /home/aymeric/dotnet_projects/sociofal/SocioFal/bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.0
Finding DbContext classes...
Using context 'ApplicationDbContext'.
```

So there is no error displayed.

Here is the context used :

```
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public DbSet<GenealogyRelation> GenealogyRelation { get; set; }

    public DbSet<FalEvent> FalEvent { get; set; }
    public DbSet<GenealogyFalEvent> GenealogyFalEvent { get; set; }
    public DbSet<BaptemeFalEvent> BaptemeFalEvent { get; set; }

    public DbSet<AdoptionFalEvent> AdoptionFalEvent { get; set; }

    public DbSet<ConfirmationFalEvent> ConfirmationFalEvent { get; set; }


    public DbSet<GenealogyCityAndFieldFalEvent> GenealogyCityAndFieldFalEvent { get; set; }


    public DbSet<City> City { get; set; }
    public DbSet<FalProfile> FalProfile { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SocialProfile> SocialProfile { get; set; }

    public DbSet<StudyField> StudyField { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserStudyField> UserStudyField { get; set; }

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<GenealogyFalEvent>().ToTable("GenealogyFalEvent");
        builder.Entity<BaptemeFalEvent>().ToTable("BaptemeFalEvent");
        builder.Entity<ConfirmationFalEvent>().ToTable("ConfirmationFalEvent");
        builder.Entity<AdoptionFalEvent>().ToTable("AdoptionFalEvent");
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
        // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
        // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        builder.Entity<GenealogyRelation>().HasKey((e) => new {e.ChildID, e.GenealogyFalEventID, e.ParentID});
        builder.Entity<UserCity>().HasKey(u => new {u.CityID, u.UserID});
        builder.Entity<UserStudyField>().HasKey(u => new {u.StudyFieldID, u.UserID});

    }
}
```

Why doesn't EF Core create a migration file ?

Comment: Can you try running above command with -verbose flag and post that output?

Comment: There is no output after "Using context 'ApplicationDbContext'."? That may be sign that code to generate migration is still running (possibly stuck in infinite loop)

Comment: I haven't thought about that because the command line was not blocked after that, i edited my question so that you can see the ApplicationDbContext code, don't know if EF Core is crashing with the composite keys i have used ?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong here. Can you file a bug on https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework with full repro with steps and model classes?

Comment: Did you ever work out what the problem is - I've the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

does your model really need a migration ? if you did not modify it since last migration ef may not need to generate a migration.

Just a guess not sure though.

Comment: Yes, i have created a new structure for my model, so there are new properties in my context. I have made a dotnet ef database drop but it doesn't generate the file for recreating the database.